# WHERE clause for a variable from a textbox

Tags: sql

I usually write my `WHERE` clause like this:

```
WHERE (InvoiceTable.ClientName LIKE '%' + @ClientName + '%' )
```

But now I'd like to write a `WHERE` clause that will give me all the data that is less than an input, say for example 5. So if I want all the data with a `PriceRatio` of less than 5, my input into the textbox is 5.

How do I write this?

Comment: Are you putting this into another program or programming language? I don't understand the use of a textbox in SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want your `where` clause to be like so:

```
where priceratio < cast(@input_number as int)
```

Just be sure the data type is as you expect, for example if the input is always going to be an integer then the above will be fine unless it's a large integer, and similarly with a decimal then the integer above in inappropriate.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928%28SQL.90%29.aspx) for details.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean:

```
Select * from table where PriceRatio < 5
```